# Parsing multiple Mqtt string arrays with multiple delegates in unity to multiple AR objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mqtt

I am working on a project where i turn a DJI drone into a Advanced UAV from call of duty and I'm using unity for it with C# as a client and Python as a server. I am having trouble implementing what i want the code to do.

Basically I want to parse three sets of arrays. each array is corresponding to a cube game object. Based on each game object, I want it to read the correct MQTT messages and assign the array as the `transport.position` of the current game object based on the game objects name.

My MQTT messages are displaying over console and my code doesn't have any errors as it runs but the blocks don't stay in place rather spawn in and out of location.

Before I added the drone and object location delegates everything spawned fine. where did i go wrong? Posting the code i have below so far. I guess I'm trying to learn where I messed up so I can formulate a proper solution. I am doing this so I can showcase an ability to solve the problem but I'm the only programmer I know so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or what section of the code I'm messing up on other then I feel like I'm making something redundant.

---

### edit

I think i might have to create pre fabs for each object i anticipate on the field, from there i need to create classes for those objects with get and set methods. I need to also create the script over again for each object.

````
```lang-csharp
public void Update()
    {
        while (!_messageQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string message;
            if (_messageQueue.TryDequeue(out message))
            {
                _messageDelegate(message);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (!_droneLocationQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string droneLocation;
            if (_droneLocationQueue.TryDequeue(out droneLocation))
            {
                _messageDelegate2(droneLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (!_objectLocationQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string objectLocation;
            if (_objectLocationQueue.TryDequeue(out objectLocation))
            {
                _messageDelegate3(objectLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```







```lang-csharp
private void HandleMessage(string message)
    {
        if (LarTarget.name == GameObject.Find("LarTarget").ToString())
            {
                var splittedStrings = message.Split(' ');
                if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
                latitude = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
                longitude  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
                altitude = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
                LarTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude, longitude, altitude);
            }
        else if(objectLocationTarget.name == GameObject.Find("objectLocationTarget").ToString())
            {   
                var splittedStrings = message.Split(' ');
                if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
                latitude1 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
                longitude1  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
                altitude1 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
                objectLocationTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude1, longitude1, altitude1);
        }
        else {
                var splittedStrings = message.Split(' ');
                if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
                latitude2 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
                longitude2  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
                altitude2 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
                droneTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude2, longitude2, altitude2);
        }
    }


```
````

full code in this block

````
```lang-csharp

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using NetMQ;
using NetMQ.Sockets;


public class NetMqListener
{
    
    private readonly Thread _listenerWorker;
    private readonly Thread _listenerWorker2;
    private readonly Thread _listenerWorker3;

    private bool _listenerCancelled;

    public delegate void MessageDelegate(string message);
    public delegate void MessageDelegate2(string droneLocation);
    public delegate void MessageDelegate3(string objectLocation);

    private readonly MessageDelegate _messageDelegate;
    private readonly MessageDelegate2 _messageDelegate2;
    private readonly MessageDelegate3 _messageDelegate3;

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _messageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _droneLocationQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _objectLocationQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    private void ListenerWork()
    {
        AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();
        using (var subSocket = new SubscriberSocket())
        {
            subSocket.Options.ReceiveHighWatermark = 1000;
            subSocket.Connect("tcp://192.168.1.5:12345");
            subSocket.Subscribe("");
            while (!_listenerCancelled)
            {
                string frameString;
                if (!subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(out frameString)) continue;
                Debug.Log(frameString);
                _messageQueue.Enqueue(frameString);
            }
            subSocket.Close();
        }
        NetMQConfig.Cleanup();
    }
    private void ListenerWork2()
    {
        AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();
        using (var subSocket = new SubscriberSocket())
        {
            subSocket.Options.ReceiveHighWatermark = 1000;
            subSocket.Connect("tcp://192.168.1.5:12345");
            subSocket.Subscribe("");
            while (!_listenerCancelled)
            {
                string frameString2;
                if (!subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(out frameString2)) continue;
                Debug.Log(frameString2);
                _objectLocationQueue.Enqueue(frameString2);
                
            }
            subSocket.Close();
        }
        NetMQConfig.Cleanup();
    }
    private void ListenerWork3()
    {
        AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();
        using (var subSocket = new SubscriberSocket())
        {
            subSocket.Options.ReceiveHighWatermark = 1000;
            subSocket.Connect("tcp://192.168.1.5:12345");
            subSocket.Subscribe("");
            while (!_listenerCancelled)
            {
                string frameString3;
                if (!subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(out frameString3)) continue;
                Debug.Log(frameString3);
                _droneLocationQueue.Enqueue(frameString3);
                
            }
            subSocket.Close();
        }
        NetMQConfig.Cleanup();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        while (!_messageQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string message;
            if (_messageQueue.TryDequeue(out message))
            {
                _messageDelegate(message);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (!_droneLocationQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string droneLocation;
            if (_droneLocationQueue.TryDequeue(out droneLocation))
            {
                _messageDelegate2(droneLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while (!_objectLocationQueue.IsEmpty)
        {
            string objectLocation;
            if (_objectLocationQueue.TryDequeue(out objectLocation))
            {
                _messageDelegate3(objectLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public NetMqListener(MessageDelegate messageDelegate, MessageDelegate2 messageDelegate2, MessageDelegate3 messageDelegate3)
    {
        _messageDelegate = messageDelegate;
        _messageDelegate2 = messageDelegate2;
        _messageDelegate3 = messageDelegate3;
        _listenerWorker = new Thread(ListenerWork);
        _listenerWorker2 = new Thread(ListenerWork2);
        _listenerWorker3 = new Thread(ListenerWork3);
        
    }
    

    public void Start()
    {
        _listenerCancelled = false;
        _listenerWorker.Start();
        _listenerWorker2.Start();
        _listenerWorker3.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _listenerCancelled = true;
        _listenerWorker.Join();
        _listenerWorker2.Join();
        _listenerWorker3.Join();
    }
}

public class LocativeTargetClient : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("Google Maps Coordinates")]
    public float latitude;
    public float latitude1;
    public float latitude2;
    public float longitude;
    public float longitude1;
    public float longitude2;
    public float altitude;
    public float altitude1;
    public float altitude2;
    public GameObject LarTarget;
    public GameObject objectLocationTarget;
    public GameObject droneTarget;

    //[Header("Enable")]
    //public float MaximumDistance=1000;

    private double raioTerra = 6372797.560856f;
    private readonly Thread _listenerWorker;
    private readonly Thread _listenerWorker2;
    private readonly Thread _listenerWorker3;
    private NetMqListener _netMqListener;
    private NetMqListener _netMqListener2;
    private NetMqListener _netMqListener3;

    private bool _listenerCancelled;
    public delegate void MessageDelegate(string message);
    public delegate void MessageDelegate2(string droneLocation);
    public delegate void MessageDelegate3(string objectLocation);

    private readonly MessageDelegate _messageDelegate;
    private readonly MessageDelegate2 _messageDelegate2;
    private readonly MessageDelegate3 _messageDelegate3;

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _messageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _droneLocationQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _objectLocationQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    private void ListenerWork()
    {
        AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();
        using (var subSocket = new SubscriberSocket())
        {
            subSocket.Options.ReceiveHighWatermark = 1000;
            subSocket.Connect("tcp://192.168.200.245:12345");
            subSocket.Subscribe("");
            while (!_listenerCancelled)
            {
                string frameString;
                if (!subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(out frameString)) continue;
                Debug.Log(frameString);
                _messageQueue.Enqueue(frameString);
            }
            subSocket.Close();
        }
        NetMQConfig.Cleanup();
    }
    private void ListenerWork2()
    {
        AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();
        using (var subSocket = new SubscriberSocket())
        {
            subSocket.Options.ReceiveHighWatermark = 1000;
            subSocket.Connect("tcp://192.168.200.245:12345");
            subSocket.Subscribe("");
            while (!_listenerCancelled)
            {
                string frameString2;
                if (!subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(out frameString2)) continue;
                Debug.Log(frameString2);
                _droneLocationQueue.Enqueue(frameString2);
            }
            subSocket.Close();
        }
        NetMQConfig.Cleanup();
    }
    private void ListenerWork3()
    {
        AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();
        using (var subSocket = new SubscriberSocket())
        {
            subSocket.Options.ReceiveHighWatermark = 1000;
            subSocket.Connect("tcp://192.168.200.245:12345");
            subSocket.Subscribe("");
            while (!_listenerCancelled)
            {
                string frameString3;
                if (!subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(out frameString3)) continue;
                Debug.Log(frameString3);
                _objectLocationQueue.Enqueue(frameString3);
            }
            subSocket.Close();
        }
        NetMQConfig.Cleanup();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        //print(raioTerra + " " + longitude);
        _netMqListener = new NetMqListener(HandleMessage);
        _netMqListener2 = new NetMqListener(HandleDroneLocation);
        _netMqListener3 = new NetMqListener(HandleObjectLocation);
        _netMqListener.Start();
        _netMqListener2.Start();
        _netMqListener3.Start();
    }
    private void HandleMessage(string message)
    {
        if (LarTarget.name == GameObject.Find("LarTarget").ToString())
            {
                var splittedStrings = message.Split(' ');
                if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
                latitude = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
                longitude  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
                altitude = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
                LarTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude, longitude, altitude);
            }
        else if(objectLocationTarget.name == GameObject.Find("objectLocationTarget").ToString())
            {   
                var splittedStrings = message.Split(' ');
                if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
                latitude1 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
                longitude1  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
                altitude1 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
                objectLocationTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude1, longitude1, altitude1);
        }
        else {
                var splittedStrings = message.Split(' ');
                if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
                latitude2 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
                longitude2  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
                altitude2 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
                droneTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude2, longitude2, altitude2);
        }
    }
    private void HandleObjectLocation(string objectLocation)
    {
        if (objectLocationTarget.name == GameObject.Find("objectLocationTarget").ToString()){
            var splittedStrings = objectLocation.Split(' ');
            if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
            latitude1 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
            longitude1  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
            altitude1 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
            objectLocationTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude1, longitude1, altitude1);
        }
        else if(LarTarget.name == GameObject.Find("LarTarget").ToString())
            {
                var splittedStrings = objectLocation.Split(' ');
                if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
                latitude = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
                longitude  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
                altitude = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
                LarTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude, longitude, altitude);
            }
        else {
                var splittedStrings = objectLocation.Split(' ');
                if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
                latitude2 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
                longitude2  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
                altitude2 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
                droneTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude2, longitude2, altitude2);
        }
    }
    private void HandleDroneLocation(string droneLocation)
    {
        if (droneTarget.name == GameObject.Find("droneTarget").ToString()){
            var splittedStrings = droneLocation.Split(' ');
            if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
            latitude2 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
            longitude2  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
            altitude2 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
            droneTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude2, longitude2, altitude2);
        }
        else if(LarTarget.name == GameObject.Find("LarTarget").ToString())
        {
            var splittedStrings = droneLocation.Split(' ');
            if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
            latitude = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
            longitude  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
            altitude = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
            LarTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude, longitude, altitude);
        }
        else 
        {
            var splittedStrings = droneLocation.Split(' ');
            if (splittedStrings.Length != 3) return;
            latitude1 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[0]);
            longitude1  = float.Parse(splittedStrings[1]);
            altitude1 = float.Parse(splittedStrings[2]);
            objectLocationTarget.transform.position = new Vector3(latitude1, longitude1, altitude1);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 coord = calculaPosCoordCam();
        Vector3 coord2 = calculaPosCoordCam1();
        Vector3 coord3 = calculaPosCoordCam2();
        LarTarget.transform.position = coord;
        objectLocationTarget.transform.position = coord2;
        droneTarget.transform.position = coord3;
        //print(coord.x +" " + coord.y + " " + coord.z);
        _netMqListener.Update();
        _netMqListener2.Update();
        _netMqListener3.Update();
    }


    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _netMqListener.Stop();
        _netMqListener2.Stop();
        _netMqListener3.Stop();
    }


    private Vector3 calculaPosCoordCam()
    {
        

        double dlat = latitude - LocativeGPS.Instance.latitude;
        dlat = getCoordEmMetrosDeRaio(raioTerra, dlat);

        double dlon = longitude - LocativeGPS.Instance.longitude;

        double raioLat = Mathf.Cos((float)latitude) * raioTerra;
        dlon = getCoordEmMetrosDeRaio(raioLat, dlon);


        double dalt = altitude - 0.0f;// LocativeGPS.Instance.altitude; 
        return new Vector3((float)dlat, (float)dalt, (float)dlon);
    }

    private Vector3 calculaPosCoordCam1()
    {
        

        double dlat1 = latitude1 - LocativeGPS.Instance.latitude;
        dlat1 = getCoordEmMetrosDeRaio(raioTerra, dlat);

        double dlon1 = longitude1 - LocativeGPS.Instance.longitude;

        double raioLat1 = Mathf.Cos((float)latitude1) * raioTerra;
        dlon1 = getCoordEmMetrosDeRaio(raioLat1, dlon1);


        double dalt1 = altitude1 - 0.0f;// LocativeGPS.Instance.altitude; 
        return new Vector3((float)dlat1, (float)dalt1, (float)dlon1);
    }
    private Vector3 calculaPosCoordCam2()
    {
        

        double dlat2 = latitude2 - LocativeGPS.Instance.latitude;
        dlat2 = getCoordEmMetrosDeRaio(raioTerra, dlat2);

        double dlon2 = longitude2 - LocativeGPS.Instance.longitude;

        double raioLat2 = Mathf.Cos((float)latitude2) * raioTerra;
        dlon2 = getCoordEmMetrosDeRaio(raioLat2, dlon2);


        double dalt2 = altitude2 - 0.0f;// LocativeGPS.Instance.altitude; 
        return new Vector3((float)dlat2, (float)dalt2, (float)dlon2);
    }



    private double getCoordEmMetrosDeRaio(double raio, double angulo)
    {
        double metros = (raio / 180) * Mathf.PI;//
        metros *= angulo;
        return metros;
    }


}
}
````

Comment: That's...a lot of code.

Comment: the first block of code is where i think the problem lies, specifically the update method. maybe i need to be creating a class for each delegate and a get set method for the lat long altitude.